# Failed to get tokens using Azure AD and SPA

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory

I am developing my web app, it is a single page application. I want to integrate it with Azure Aactive Directory to login users and call microsoft graph API .
I am following this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc .

But seems it is not so smoothly when I tried to get an ID token or access token, I always got an error:
`blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` . How could I solve it ?Am I in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MSAL.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As superstar @GauravMantri mentioned, if you are developing a SPA, you should use `MSAL.js` to log in users and get tokens. Call REST API directly not works here.

Just try the .html code below to log in users and get an access token to Microsoft Graph API:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Azure AD test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.4.4/js/msal.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div >
                    
        <button id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign in</button><br/>
        <div id="WelcomeMessage"/><br/>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var clientAppID = "<your public client Azure AD APP ID>"
    var tenantID = "<your tenant ID>"
    
    var demoScops = {
         scopes:["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"]
    }

    var msalConfig = {
             auth: {
                 clientId: clientAppID,
                 authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID
            },
             cache: {
                 cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                 storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
    };
     

    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);
             
    
    function signIn() {
     
         myMSALObj.loginPopup(demoScops).then(function (loginResponse) {
            console.log(loginResponse);
            initPage();
             
         }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
     }
     
    function initPage(){
        showWelcomeMessage();
        callGraphApi();
     }
     

     
     function showWelcomeMessage() {
             
         var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
         divWelcome.innerHTML = 'welcome! ' + myMSALObj.account.userName + '</br>';
         var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
         loginbutton.innerHTML = 'sign out';
         loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
     }
     
     function callGraphApi(){
         myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(demoScops).then(function (tokenResponse) {
         
             var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
             $.ajax({
                 url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
                 type: "GET",
                 async: false,
                 beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ accessToken);},
                 success: function(data) { 
                    console.log(data)
                 }
              });
              
              
         }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              })
        }     
     
   
 
     
     function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
         if (error) {
             console.log(error);
         }
     }
     
     function requiresInteraction(errorCode) {
         if (!errorCode || !errorCode.length) {
             return false;
         }
         return errorCode === "consent_required" ||
             errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
             errorCode === "login_required";
     }
     

     var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
     var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
     var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
     var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
     var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
     var isEdge = msedge > 0;

     var loginType = isIE ? "REDIRECT" : "POPUP";
     
     if (loginType === 'POPUP') {
          if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
              initPage()
          }
     }
     else if (loginType === 'REDIRECT') {
         document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
              myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
         };
         if (myMSALObj.getAccount() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
              initPage()
          }
     } else {
         console.error('Please set a valid login type');
     }
     
     

      function signOut() {
          window.localStorage.clear();
          myMSALObj.logout();
      }
    
</script>

</html>
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the quick response, I am testing and will back to you later